# Create a function from an interval

Tags: r

I have this matrix in R, called MRASTI genereatet from the command

```
MRASTI <- matrix(sample(data.matrix(pune, rownames.force=NA), 
                        22000, replace=TRUE),
                 nrow=1000, byrow=TRUE)
```

and i have this interval

```
x[(x>14274.19)&(x<14458.17)]
```

which is a vector with 9998 elements. I want to calculate this formula:

`y <- 1 / length(MRASTI) * sum((MRASTI - x)^2)`

where x takes values from the previous interval. How can i do it in R?
Thank you

I try this commands:

```
> for (i in 1:9998) {y<-1/length(MRASTI)*sum((MRASTI-x[i])^2)}
```

but this generates just a single value
Thank you

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.  As-is, your data matrix needs an object called "pune" to work.  Try using `dput`.

Comment: Also, can you try to use the formatting tools provided by the site and not your own random markup? Space out your code a bit. Have a look at what I've done in editing your Q to see how to space out and format code. To format code blocks, highlight the code and click the icon that looks like two braces: `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `y` in this line:

```
for (i in 1:9998) {
    y <- 1/length(MRASTI)*sum((MRASTI-x[i])^2)
}
```

At each loop iteration you are overwriting `y`. The simple solution is:

```
y <- numeric(length = 9998)
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
    y[i] <- 1 / length(MRASTI) * sum((MRASTI - x[i])^2)
}
```

Without seeing some example objects and the code to create them and run your code, it is difficult to say if we could vectorise this for you so you don't need a loop.